# Fix missing Reference?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, ms-office

I have an Excel Application that when a user clicks a button the below line of code fires to copy the entire Excel Workbook with a new name to a new folder location:

```
' Save a copy of workbook to Archive folder
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs (CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop") & "\Inspections\Archive\FeedSampleReport-" & Environ$("Username") & "-" & Strings.Format(Now(), "mmddyyyy") & ".xlsm")
```

On my system everything works fine, but on theirs `Environ$` flags with `Compile error: Can't find project or library`. When I checked references of both machines, I found that they have one marked `MISSING: Microsoft ActiveX Data Object 6.1 Library`.

How do I fix this, and what can I do to ensure new users have necessary references?

EDIT: More information. The issue is only on users with Windows XP machines. My development machine is running Windows7, and the few end-users that are also up to using Windows7 do not have the issue either.

Comment: For you propose, I think you can use previous ActiveX version.

Comment: But how does that help the Missing Reference problem?

Comment: Nothing. Thats why it's a comment not a answer ;-). You can change the ActiveX to 2.1 and try to see if your code works fine. I just showing that you can avoid this check/verify/alert changing your ActiveX version.

Comment: This page can help to: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2640696 and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937730

Comment: you could also late bind your code and remove the reference completely

Comment: @JosieP, late bind my code?

Comment: see more complete answer I just posted ;-)

Answer (score 0):

to late bind, instead of declaring objects as a specific type (like ADODB.Connection) you declare them as Object and use

```
Dim cn as Object
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
```

rather than

```
Dim cn as ADODB.Connection
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
```

to instantiate them. you will also have to declare any constants you use from the referenced library (or replace them with a literal value) so for example you might add

```
Const adOpenStatic As Long = 3 
Const adCmdText As Long = 1
Const adLockReadOnly As Long = 1
```

because without the reference to ADO set those would have no values to VBA.

Comment: I'm sorry Josie, maybe I'm just not quite on the same level as you. What does creating an object to declare as ADODB have to do with my code flagging `Envirion$` as a missing Reference on XP machines?

Comment: that is only flagged as an error because of the missing ADO reference. if you remove the need to *use* a reference at all, it can't go missing and therefore will remove that error :-)

Comment: Ok, I think I get it now. How would I go about removing the ADO reference in this case though? The code is flagging `Environ$` as the issue.

Comment: once you revise the code to use late binding as I showed and remove the ADO reference, you will have no problem with Environ

Comment: Ok, but what exactly in my code then is considered an ADO reference?

Comment: per your original, in the references dialog you have: MISSING: Microsoft ActiveX Data Object 6.1 Library. once you alter the code you can uncheck that completely and then the problem will disappear